# TabHost and FontAwesome Icons

Tags: java, android, fonts

How do I return a font awesome icon to a title tab for tabhost? Right now it's displaying nothing.....My method below works for PagerTabStrip whats the difference?

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");

    //this wont show the icon, it's blank:
    tab1.setIndicator(icon_giver(font,  "\uf0c0"));




//my method is:

public CharSequence icon_giver(Typeface font, String icon_id){
    String title_of_page = "";
    SpannableStringBuilder styled;
    title_of_page = icon_id;
    styled = new SpannableStringBuilder(title_of_page);
    styled.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, title_of_page.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    return styled;
}
```

Comment: ...so what **is** it doing? We can't debug things that we don't have enough information to debug.

Comment: doesn't show the icon, it's blank

Comment: **What** doesn't show it? This question needs some serious improvement before it's in an answerable state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I had to do this:

[TextDrawable](https://github.com/devunwired/textdrawable) project on github. You can modify it such that Font-Awesome is used as the typeface.

I applied it by using:

```
TextDrawable draw_icon = new TextDrawable(this);
draw_icon.setText(icon_giver(font, "\uf0c0"));
tab1.setIndicator("",draw_icon);
```